# how to guarantee that the box that contains date and time will be always centered after calling the card in list view

Tags: flutter, dart

i am a beginner in flutter , i am trying to correct the display of this widget in flutter ,
the problem is that this widget is not responsive where the name of the teams when they are long they can make the screen out of range , and also the time and date zone is not always centered , i am searching how to make the date and the time zone always centered in the screen in all the cases , how to replace the padding ? by container?? what prosperities to change???

my goal is to make the date and the time centered in all the cases and my second goal is to find a solution for the width of screen when the name of teams are long

here my widget class :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BroadcastSchedule extends StatelessWidget  {

  String home;
  String homeImage;
  String away;
  String awayImage;
  String time;
  String date;

  BroadcastSchedule(this.home,this.homeImage,this.away,this.awayImage,this.time,this.date);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child:
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.homeImage),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width:10.0),
            Spacer(),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.home),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[700],
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
               ),
               child: Column(

                 children: [
                   Text(this.time,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 18.0,
                       color: Colors.white,
                   ),),
                   const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                   Text(this.date,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 16.0,
                       color: Colors.white
                   ),),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
      Expanded(
            child : Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.away),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
      ),
            Spacer(),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.awayImage),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the screen capture :
[image]

how can we replace padding that contains the date and time of a match by something that will be centered in all the cases

Comment: There are total 5 widgets in a single row it mean time always come Centre. Best way is use MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, inside Row Widget

Comment: did not work , same problem , can you give an alternative for padding???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you're looking for this.

final Result Looks like this.

[Final Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGCiZ.png)

```
class BroadcastSchedule extends StatelessWidget {
  final String home;
  final String homeImage;
  final String away;
  final String awayImage;
  final String time;
  final String date;

  BroadcastSchedule({
    this.home,
    this.homeImage,
    this.away,
    this.awayImage,
    this.time,
    this.date,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.homeImage),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(this.home),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        this.time,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        this.date,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          this.away,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.awayImage),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did not work , the date and time is not centered ,

Comment: and no need to change the styling of my widget , need just to make it responsive

Comment: i need the box that contains the date and time to be always in the center for all the cards that will be called later in a list view

Comment: Date and time is centered

Comment: i want the same styling no changes , i need just to make sure when i will call the card in the list view no thing is misplaced , this is the only goal

Comment: Check Now. Everything will now remain its place. No Changes

Comment: wow perfect man , so what should i learn from my mistake , why your code works?

Comment: Your code didn't work because Widgets took the space accordingly. I Gave them a Fixed Width that's why they can't increase their width.

Comment: is it flex property what made it with fixed width?

Comment: Yes. Flex adjust their width

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
       children: <Widget> [
       Text(this.home),
       const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
       ],
       ),
```

Please change it. Don't use the column it's unneccessary.

Instead, You can use a container of fixed-sized (fixed height and width). So, that it can wrap text according to its length.

The problem caused by the length of this.home string. You can wrap that text inside the container of fixed length. so, that your date and time is shown always at the center.

Try this code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BroadcastSchedule extends StatelessWidget  {

  String home;
  String homeImage;
  String away;
  String awayImage;
  String time;
  String date;

  BroadcastSchedule(this.home,this.homeImage,this.away,this.awayImage,this.time,this.date);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child:
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.homeImage),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width:10.0),
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.22,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget> [
                  Text(this.home,softWrap: true,),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[700],
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
               ),
               child: Column(

                 children: [
                   Text(this.time,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 18.0,
                       color: Colors.white,
                   ),),
                   const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                   Text(this.date,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 16.0,
                       color: Colors.white
                   ),),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
      Expanded(
            child : Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.away),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
      ),
            Spacer(),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.awayImage),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

IF it's not center try to change the length of the container.